# Load external Javascript on function call

Tags: javascript, function, external

I would like to know how to load an external Javascript into my document from a function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is one way:

```
function loadDaFun() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = '/path/to/your/script.js';
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: type's not necessary, makes no difference (by the way)

Answer (score 13):

The [@seth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375714/load-external-javascript-on-function-call/1375726#1375726)'s answer is completely right, but you don't need to leave the inserted `script` element on the DOM, you can remove it just after it is loaded, and also you might want to know *when* the inserted script is ready to use, for example you can:

```
function loadScript(url, completeCallback) {
   var script = document.createElement('script'), done = false,
       head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   script.src = url;
   script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
          this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {
       done = true;
       completeCallback();

      // IE memory leak
      script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
      head.removeChild( script );
    }
  };
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Usage:

```
loadScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js",
            function () { alert('jQuery has been loaded.'); });
```