# Is it possible to load an external JavaScript file by flash and then call its methods

Tags: javascript, flash

I am talking about doing something like this:
[Load external Javascript on function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375714/load-external-javascript-on-function-call)

from flash by using ExternalInterface probably

Answer (score 1):

Call a JavaScript function from Flash that adds a new script tag to the head. The only difference in the function is called from Flash.